# How to iterate over a std::map from start and end simultaneously?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I want to traverse a map with two iterator simultaneously, one from start and one from end, something like below.

```
map<int, int> m;
for (auto i = m.begin(), j = m.rbegin(); i != m.end(), j != m.rend(); ++i, ++j) 
{
}
```

But getting following error.

```
error C3538: in a declarator-list 'auto' must always deduce to the same type
```

Also I would like to iterate until `i < j` of the code snippet. Which is only till midway from both start and end of the map.

Comment: `i<j` requires random-access iterators, which `map` does not have.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but `i != m.end(), j != m.rend()` should be `i != m.end() && j != m.rend()`. As written, it's equivalent to `j != m.rend()`.

Comment: If you have your heart set on that pattern, you can use destructuring `for ( auto [i, j] = make_tuple(m.begin(), m.rbegin()); i != m.end() && j != m.rend(); ++i, ++j)`.  Note that the comma operator in the `i != m.end(), j != m.rend()` *iteration expression* isn't going to do what (I think) you intended.

Answer (score 2):

The init-statement of a for loop can be empty. To restrict the variables to a scope as narrow as possible I suggest to add some extra `{}`. You can get the forward iterator from the reverse iterator via `base()` and then compare the two:

```
map<int, int> m;
{
    auto i = m.begin();
    auto j = m.rbegin();
    for (; i != j.base() && i != std::next(j.base()); ++i, ++j) 
    {
        std::cout << i->first << " " << j->first << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P8n1z1eeo)

As [Useless explains nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393499/4117728), you need to be careful with incrementing the iterators in parallel and comparing them via `!=`. Acutally, one could argue that you are using the wrong container when you want to iterate its elements in that fashion. Iterating elements in order isn't `std::map`s strength.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` iterators are bidirectional, so you don't need to use a reverse iterator at all.

Note that in the naive translation:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(), j = m.end(); i != m.end() && j != m.begin(); ++i, --j) 
{
}
```

you need to dereference `(j-1)` in the body (this is the part the reverse iterator was taking care of for you).

---

> Also I would like to iterate until i < j of the code snippet

You can absolutely stop when `i == j`, *but* ... you have to be careful around your increment & decrement.

Something like:

```
for (auto i = m.begin(), j = m.end();
     i != j && std::next(i) != j;
     ++i, --j) 
{
}
```

might work, but check carefully through the logic for containers with zero, one, two elements, and decide exactly what *should* happen for those cases.

Comment: cheers, I knew I was going to get at least one detail wrong in that bit.

Comment: cheers, I didnt know it but your answer made me realize that my first attempt was wrong :)